# MassTransit receive a message in Raw or XML format

Tags: xml, masstransit, raw

I am trying to get an XML message from a queue (hosted by ActiveMQ). It works perfectly as long as I use JSON messages, but I do not get it to work with raw text or XML messages.

I have tried to change the `ContentType`:

```java
cfg.DefaultContentType = new ContentType(@"application/vnd.masstransit+xml");
```

I also tried to create a custom Deserializer.

I always end up with a deserialization error of the Json Deserializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to [configure the proper deserializer](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/integrations/serialization#newtonsoft), such as:

`cfg.UseRawXmlDeserializer()`

(requires the MassTransit.Newtonsoft package)

Comment: Thanks Chris, I missed the NewtonSoft package :-)